# redirecting html page to another html

Tags: html, redirect

I have to redirect a website to another website, before it is shown. I have tried using .htaccess but it is giving me problems. I have also used javavscript and meta but it does not work before the loading of a page from which I want to transfer. help?

Comment: What do you currently have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: The file had exactly the same code which has been posted as asnwer below and after using that file my page stopped opening completely.

Comment: Thanks everybody I write here what I did and it worked :)

I created file named "htaccess.txt" and data inside it is: 
Redirect 301 /example/90_10.htm http://www.google.com

After uploading this file on server, I renamed it to ".htaccess"
Then it worked :)

Answer (score 7):

try this one

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="N; URL=other-web-address">
```

where N is the approximate number of seconds that you want the current web page to be displayed before the browser automatically goes to the other web address. If N = 0, then the browser should go immediately to the other web address.

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Where is the solution in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

put this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://stackoverflow.com/">
```

in the html head tag (replace `http://stackoverflow.com/` with the url u want).

Comment: even after using that it first load's page then redirects it. What I am looking for is that the page be transferred to the other url as soon it starts loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will definitely work!!! This doesn't let your first page content to be displayed rather it will let the user go to the redirected page directly.
Write this inside head tag after `script type="text/javascript"`

`window.location="http://www.redirectedlocation.com";`

Comment: This will definitely ONLY work if Javascript is enabled in the client.